# Zen Master verse about an ‘eternal battle on the temple steps’

Tags: reference-request, zen

I think I once read a Zen Master verse about an “eternal battle on the temple steps”, possibly it was referenced by Hakuin(?).

Please could you let me know who said this, and what the verse was?